# Prometheus query to get number of major GCs per min for a spring boot application

Tags: garbage-collection, prometheus, monitoring, prometheus-alertmanager

I have a requirement to put a Prometheus alert if number of major GCs per min for a spring boot application exceeds to a certain number.
I am trying to write Prometheus query for that.

I got to know one metric named `jvm_gc_collection_seconds_sum` but this metric is no longer available after spring boot 2.

Any other way in certain query to get this data?

Answer (score 0):

In Spring Boot 2.x, the metrics related to garbage collection (GC) have been changed and are no longer available under the `jvm_gc_collection_seconds_sum` metric name. Instead, Spring Boot 2.x uses Micrometer as the metrics library, which provides a different set of metric names.

To monitor the number of major GCs per minute for your Spring Boot application, you can use the following Prometheus query:

```
rate(jvm_gc_pause_seconds_count{gc="G1 Young Generation"}[1m])
```

This query calculates the rate of increase in the count of GC pauses in the G1 Young Generation over the last 1 minute. The `jvm_gc_pause_seconds_count` metric represents the total number of GC pauses for a specific garbage collector algorithm, and the `gc` label specifies the type of GC. In this case, it's set to "G1 Young Generation" to capture major GCs.

You can configure the threshold for the number of major GCs per minute that triggers an alert in Prometheus. For example, if you want to alert when the rate exceeds 10 major GCs per minute, you can modify the query as follows:

```
rate(jvm_gc_pause_seconds_count{gc="G1 Young Generation"}[1m]) > 10
```

This query will return a boolean result (`true` or `false`) indicating whether the rate of major GCs per minute exceeds 10 or not. You can use this query as an alerting condition in Prometheus to trigger an alert.

Please note that the exact metric names and labels may vary depending on the garbage collector used by your Spring Boot application, so make sure to adjust them accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But in my case, this query is giving no result. In my application Prometheus, I am getting below metrics wrt "jvm_gc_pause_seconds_count" 

# TYPE jvm_gc_pause_seconds summary

jvm_gc_pause_seconds_count{action="end of major GC"....

jvm_gc_pause_seconds_sum{action="end of major GC"....

jvm_gc_pause_seconds_count{action="end of minor GC".....